# How to get the last not logged-in user's within three weeks backwards?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am trying to get the users who are not logged-in within the last three weeks. I have heard about the Method Min And Max to be used but not sure how. So I would like to get the users who have not logged in last three weeks where `LoginDate` is the list of user logs:

```
    var threeWeeksAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-21);
    //userLogins is a table
         var lastLogins = lowUsers.UserLogins
                .Join(lowUsers.Clients, ul => ul.client, c => c.companyName, (ul, c) => new { ClientId = c.clientID, LoginDate = ul.dateTimeCreated, CompanyName = c.companyName })
                .Where(a => a.LoginDate <= threeWeeksAgo);
```

How can I check LoginDate with list of users who has not logged in the last three weeks.

Data:

```
Id  UserName LoginDate
1   User1    01/10/2021 13:24
2   User2    02/09/2021 13:24
3   User1    03/10/2021 13:24
4   User1    04/10/2021 13:24
5   User2    03/09/2021 13:24
```

Comment: What is the type of `userLogins`? Do you mean **userLogins**  is the list of user logs? Please add the types

Comment: userLogins is the table name.

Comment: No it isn't as you're trying to operate `.Where` on it - is it of type `string`? Which variable is the list of the data you're showing as part of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to group by client, order the dates of that group, and then compare the last login date with three weeks ago.

```
var threeWeeksAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-21);

//userLogins is a table
var lastLogins = lowUsers.UserLogins
    .Join(lowUsers.Clients, ul => ul.client, c => c.companyName, (ul, c) => new { ClientId = c.clientID, LoginDate = ul.dateTimeCreated, CompanyName = c.companyName })
    .GroupBy(x => x.ClientId)
    .Select(g => new { ClientId = g.Key, LastLoginDate = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LoginDate).FirstOrDefault()?.LoginDate}) 
    .Where(a => a.LastLoginDate <= threeWeeksAgo);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `LoginDate` is of type `DateTime` you can do the following

```
 var threeWeeksAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-21);
//userLogins is a table
var notLoggedInUsers = userLogins.Where(a=>a.LoginDate < threeWeeksAgo).ToList();
```

Comment: I want only users who have logged in before the last three weeks if a user has date where he logged in before three weeks ago and after three weeks ago then we should not display the result.

Comment: What do you mean with before three weeks ago and after three weeks ago? My proposed solution finds the `usersLogins` where the login date is before three weeks ago and provides them in a list in the variable `notLoggedInUsers`.

Comment: I have updated my code I would like to check if the user has only not logged in within the last three weeks. If the user has logged in for once within the last three weeks then I should not display him even if he has record where it shows that he logged in before three weeks ago

Comment: @user16908948 The code above does what you need - if you update your login date whenever the user logs in, the above code will filter for users who have not logged in in the past 3 weeks - have you tried it?

Comment: A user can have multiple logs. so the filter will not consider if the user has also logged in the the future. so if the condition is met then will bring a record even that the same user might has a record where he did also logged in the last three weeks.